# "Second order quantization operator" and its role in the construction of Hida spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-calculus, quantum-mechanics

As premise I know barely anything about physics and thus this question might be absolutely trivial or ill-posed.

I am starting to study the White noise theory and when constructing the infinite-dimensional analogue of the Schwartz space $S(\mathbb R^n)$, i.e. $(S)$  one way is to grab a random variable  $\psi\in L^2(S(R),\mu)$ with chaotic representation in term of Wiener-Ito integrals:

$$\psi=\sum_n I_n(f_n).$$

At this point an operator is introduced, namely

$$\Gamma (A) \psi= \sum_n I_n(A^{\otimes n} f_n),$$
where $A$ is the Hamiltonian of a harmonic oscillator, $A=-d^2/dx^2 +x^2+1$.

The author of the notes I'm reading states that this is the "second order quantization operator", also T.Hida makes allusion to such operator.

I went to Wikipedia to read about this "second order quantization" and  honestly I don't quite understand if the two things are related at all.

Do you mind giving a brief (and "for a
dumb") explanation on why this operator is called like that?
I suspect it has to do with the Fock space, since the Homogeneous chaoses are related via an isometry with the  Hilbert  space symmetric tensor power.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually hear it called "second quantization" so that might be a better keyword to look up: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/second+quantization